# Framework for partial bidirectional database synchronization

Tags: database, postgresql, grails, data-synchronization

I'm trying to optimize the backend for an information system for high-availability, which involves splitting off a part needed for time-critical client requests (front office) from the rest (back office).

Front office will have redundant application servers with load balancing for maximum performance and will use a database with pre-computed data. Back office will periodically prepare data for the front office based on client statistics and some external data.

A part of the data schema will be shared between both back and front office, but not the whole databases, only parts of some tables. The data will not need to correspond all the time, it will be synchronized between the two databases periodically. Continuous synchronization is also viable, but there is no real-time consistency requierement and it seems that batch-style synchronization would be better in terms of control, debug and backup possibilities. I expect no need for solving conflicts because data will mostly grow and change only on one side.

The solution should allow defining corresponding tables and columns and then it will insert/update new/changed rows. The solution should ideally use data model defined in Groovy classes (probably through annotations?), as both applications run on Grails. The synchronization may use the existing Grails web applications or run externally, maybe even on the database server alone (Postgresql).

There are systems for replicating whole mirrored databases, but I wasn't able to find any solution suiting my needs. Do you know of any existing framework to do help with that or to make my own is the only possibility?

Comment: Well, if you're specifying the language you want to work in you're drastically limiting your options and almost certain to have to DIY. There are existing tools like Londiste that are designed for at least part of your use case, though the "parts of" tables aspect makes it all much more awkward. Why do you want to sync only periodically? It's generally better to sync continuously, spreading the load, and just be tolerant of lag/interruptions.

Comment: @CraigRinger I only wanted to reuse the existing Java/Groovy model definition for the synchronization. I could transform it to some kind of configuration for a sync system (which doesn't have to be in Java). The "parts of tables" aspect is essential as the two sides will only hold subsets of each other's dataset (subset of both tables and columns). Thanks for the Londiste reference, I'll examine its custom handlers or the underlying PgQ. Periodical sync explanation added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Londiste from SkyTools. The project page on pgFoundry site lists quite old binaries (and is currently down), so you better build it from [source](https://github.com/markokr/skytools).

It's one direction (master-slave) only, so one has to set up two synchronization instances for bidirectional sync. Note that each instance consists of two Londiste binaries (master and slave worker) and a ticker daemon that pushes the changes.

To reduce synchronization traffic, you can extend the polling period (by default 1 second) in the configuration file or even turn it off completely by stopping the ticker and then trigger the sync manually by running SQL function `pgq.ticker` on master.

I solved the issue of partial column replication by writing a simple custom handler (`londiste.handler.TableHandler` subclass) with column-mapping configured in database. The mapping configuration is not model-driven (yet) as I originally planned, but I only need to replicate common columns, so this solution is sufficient for now.